# Datatables.net and rspec, test finish processing

Tags: rspec, capybara, phantomjs, datatables, poltergeist

I'm using capybara and phantomjs (poltergeist). 
Seems that with that driver capybara is not always waiting until ajax processing is finished so I'm geting red specs randomly. 
Is there any way to test in rspec that datatable has finished loading records ?

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question at [Selenium through Capybara not loading page with jQuery dataTables 1.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814685/selenium-through-capybara-not-loading-page-with-jquery-datatables-1-10-0) you can revert your `ajax` option to the old `fnServerData` and your specs should work again.  Not sure why using `ajax` doesn't work though.