# Selenium through Capybara not loading page with jQuery dataTables 1.10.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, datatables, jquery-datatables-rails

I upgraded our dataTables today from jQuery 1.9.2 to 1.10.0 through the https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails gem. I performed all of the upgrade steps and everything works out now in the interface as expected. I tested this both on Chrome and Firefox 30. I then went to run our specs that cover those and capybara keeps timing out whenever it goes to the page with the dataTables on it. I have tried everything I can think of to try to get the page to load fully. I see no errors coming through the test log and no javascript errors when testing through the browser. The screenshot comes back as the table is still loading.

- What can I do to further debug why the page isn't loading?
- Is there a common fix as it just happened after upgrading from jQuery 1.9.2 to 1.10.0

I figured out exactly what was causing the issue. I updated my javascript initialization for the dataTable to stop using fnServerData and to use the new ajax: 'whatever.txt' Setting that back to use fnServerData and reverting the logic behind to use the old GET parameters has fixed it for now. I still want to figure out if it's possible to fix capybara with the ajax way as the params being passed now make a lot more sense and are easier to handle.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

See the issue at https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1467

The issue is with the long uri when using a GET request. As seen in the comments, you can use thin as the server to resolve the issue, but I simply just changed my request to a POST instead of a GET and now things work fine for me.